# Cannot generate Opensearch Reports

Tags: opensearch

I've updated to `2.3` on all my OpenSearch clusters in my AWS accounts. I try to generate reports in the `Reporting Plugin`. Both pdfs and pngs, based off of Dashboards. Only 1 time ever have I been successful to generate and download a pdf report. Most of the time the progress wheel just keeps spinning, and never finishes. I do see the browser console a few errors, and a 500, but I'm just curios if this feature even works? As across different clusters, with different versions, and different report settings it seems to not work.